# How to get only specific values inside for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

In my table I am displaying data like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="Trips/Trip">
    <xsl:for-each select="Position">
        <TD><xsl:value-of select="MaxTaxFreeValue"/></TD>
        <TD><xsl:value-of select="Account"/></TD>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now, `Account` has multiple values, e.g. `6664`, `6668` etc.  In another table I only want to show the values when `Account` value is `6664`. So basically the sum of `MaxTaxFreeValue` but only if the value of `Account` is `6664`.

Can I do this with 'when'? Not really sure how to go on about this.

Comment: Please show the input XML and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: As well as showing your input XML, and the expected output, can you also say if you can use XSLT 2.0 please? In a previous question, it shows that `MaxTaxFreeValue` may contain non-numeric values like `24,00 €`. If this is still the case, then it will be much easier to achieve in XSLT 2.0. Thanks!

Comment: It looks from your stylesheet that `MaxTaxFreeValue` and `Account` are siblings. Then you migth want to be filtering out `Position` elements. Use `Position[Account = 6664]`